# Como retirar os botões do VideoView? Android

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando uma maneira de tirar ou ocultar os botões de um VideoPlayer (avançar, pausar, voltar) em android, porque o video faz parte da SplashScreen

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/intro";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);

    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.seekTo(1);
    mVideoView.start();

}
```

Tentei usar as funções `mVideoView.canPause();` mas não tive sucesso

Answer (score 2):

Tentei algumas (milhares) de vezes, consegui usando:

```
videoView.setMediaController(null)
```

Assim os botões do videoview sumiram, e ficou somente o video tocando em autoplay